# Not quite cardinal characteristics of the continuum

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory, logic, set-theory, descriptive-set-theory

*We work in $\mathsf{ZFC}$:*

---

Given an ideal $\mathcal{I}$ of subsets of $\omega^\omega$, let $\kappa_\mathcal{I}$ be the smallest cardinality of a collection $\mathfrak{C}$ of $\mathcal{I}$-positive (= not in $\mathcal{I}$) sets such that every $\mathcal{I}$-positive set contains an element of $\mathfrak{C}$ as a subset. **Note that we don't restrict attention to "tame" sets of reals here**. The ideals I'm interested in are: the *null* and *meager* ideals $\mathcal{N}$ and $\mathcal{M}$ (for the former, note that we can identify $\omega^\omega$ with the irrationals), the *dominatable* ideal $\mathcal{D}$ of sets of functions which can be dominated by a single function, and the *escapable* ideal $\mathcal{E}$ of sets of functions which can be escaped by a single function.

It's not hard to show that for each $\mathcal{I}\in\{\mathcal{M,N,D,E}\}$ we have $\aleph_1<\kappa_\mathcal{I}\le 2^{2^{\aleph_0}}$. The upper bound is trivial and the lower bound following from a quick transfinite recursion argument:

- Since every countable set is in $\mathcal{I}$, given $\mathcal{I}$-positive sets $(A_i)_{i<\omega_1}$ we can recursively build disjoint $B,C$ which each meet each $A_i$.
- Since $\omega^\omega\not\in\mathcal{I}$, at least one of $\omega^\omega\setminus B$ and $\omega^\omega\setminus C$ must be $\mathcal{I}$-positive, and by the previous bulletpoint neither $\omega^\omega\setminus B$ nor $\omega^\omega\setminus C$ contains any of the $A_i$s.

More generally, if $\mathcal{J}$ is any ideal such that $\omega^\omega\not\in\mathcal{J}$ and every set of size $<\mu$ is in $\mathcal{J}$ we have $\kappa_\mathcal{J}>\mu$.

Beyond that, however, I don't see anything interesting. My general question is, "What can we say about the $\kappa_\mathcal{I}$s of these ideals?" This is a bit open ended, so let me focus on the point my ignorance about which is most embarrassing:

> For which such $\mathcal{I}\in\{\mathcal{N,M,D,E}\}$ is it consistent with $\mathsf{ZFC}$ that $\kappa_\mathcal{I}\le 2^{\aleph_0}$?

I suspect the answer is "none," and I *strongly* suspect the answer is "none" if we replace $\le$ by $<$. However, I can't prove any of this. A big obstacle is that it's consistent that there can be an $\mathcal{I}$-positive set of cardinality much less than the continuum; this breaks all the relevant recursions I can think of.

Re: the title, while they have a similar flavor at first sip the $\kappa_\mathcal{I}$s are *not* genuine cardinal characteristics: cardinal characteristics necessarily live between $\aleph_1$ and $2^{\aleph_0}$, and the $\kappa_\mathcal{I}$s don't. That said, it is very plausible to me that there is a connection between the two topics. Note that the observation beginning with "more generally" above connects $\kappa_\mathcal{I}$ with a genuine cardinal characteristic associated to $\mathcal{I}$, namely the smallest cardinality of an $\mathcal{I}$-positive set.

Comment: What is an $\mathcal I$-positive set? The complement of a set in $\mathcal I$?

Comment: @HennoBrandsma No, it's a set not in $\mathcal{I}$. E.g. positivity with respect to the null ideal is the same as having positive outer measure. I'll edit to include this.

Comment: @Henno: Normally the positive sets are simply those that are not in the ideal.

Comment: What does it mean for a set of functions to be escapable by a single function?

Comment: @AndreasLietz $F\subseteq\omega^\omega$ is escapable by a single function iff there is some $g\in\omega^\omega$ such that $g$ escapes $f$ for each $f\in F$, where "$g$ escapes $f$" means "$g$ is not dominated by $f$."

Comment: For null/meager ideal this is consistent. See https://mathoverflow.net/questions/209081/saturation-of-null-ideal

Comment: @hot_queen Ooh, very nice! Stupid question: is it obvious that $<2^{\aleph_0}$ is impossible? This seems like it should be obvious but I don't see it.

Comment: Yes, this follows from the fact that you can partition R into continuum many non-null/non-meager sets.

Comment: @hot_queen Sorry to display my ignorance, but is *that* obvious? I don't immediately see how to do that.

Comment: Partition R into continuum many Bernstein sets, i.e., sets that meet every uncountable closed set (and therefore every uncountable analytic set). The construction is a continuum-length induction where, at each step, you put one point into one of your intended Bernstein sets, making sure that that set meets a particular uncountable closed set.

Comment: @AndreasBlass Ah, of course! I feel silly, thanks. Does something like this work for dominating/escaping? I don't see why it wouldn't, but I'm less familiar with the corresponding ideals.

Comment: In the random real model, every dominating family of size continuum has a dominating subfamily of size $\aleph_1$. This is because random forcing is $\omega^{\omega}$ bounding. So in this model, $\kappa_{\cal{E}} \leq \mathfrak{c}$.

Comment: As far as I can see, all that was used about null and meager is that any set in the ideal is disjoint from some uncountable Borel set (so that Bernstein sets aren't in the ideal). And that seems OK for your other two ideals as well.

Comment: $\kappa_{\mathcal{D}} \leq \mathfrak{c}$ also holds in the random real model for similar reasons.

Comment: @hot_queen Would you be willing to post your comments as an answer?

Comment: Sure, I will check the details and do it soon.